# How to make sound in videos louder

Tags: windows-7, video, audio, editing

Is there any application that I could use to bulk edit the videos and make its sounds louder?
There are about 47 videos with soft sound and I want to make it louder
In windows 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to convert to any format using Xillisoft HD converter and set the Audio quality to highest in left pane

Comment: This is an issue with volume, not quality.